# How to Reference An Event Handler

Tags: vb.net, subroutine

I want to activate an event handler (i.e. listbox1_selectedindexchanged) in my main subroutine

For example:

```
Private sub main()

listbox1_selectedindexchanged()

end sub
```

However, what should I put for parameter "e" and "sender" where e is the system.eventargs and sender is the object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `sender` and `e` parameter in the `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()` method then, you can call like this

```
ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(New Object, New EventArgs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to extract the code you want to share from the event handler and move it to a separate method. Instead of calling the event handler, you'd call the method from both the event handler and your sub main.

However, if you want to call the event handler directly, you can specify the control as sender (in your case `listbox1`) and `EventArgs.Empty` (thanks @AndrewMorton)  as parameter "e":

```
listbox1_selectedindexchanged(listbox1, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Comment: `EventArgs.Empty` is available.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: thanks for the hint. Should be slightly more efficient.